# Simplify dope sheet

Tags: dopesheet

Is there a way to simplify the dope sheet to only show the shader nodetree keyframe?
[image]

Comment: There is funnel icon at the top right in the dope sheet panel called filters. Did you try it?

Comment: I did, but I'm searching for a way to only display one single shader nodetree keyframe per material.